# Merge y reduce, Empty DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x

Dispongo de los siguientes dataframes.

```
portfolio_df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 33 entries, 0 to 32
Data columns (total 5 columns):
Acquisition Date    33 non-null datetime64[ns]
Ticker              33 non-null object
Quantity            33 non-null float64
Unit Cost           33 non-null float64
Cost Basis          33 non-null float64
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), float64(3), object(1)

adj_close_start

          Ticker Fech_Ini_Anal  Cotiz_Fech_Ini
0         Acatis    2016-01-04         217.320
1       Avantage    2016-01-04          11.391
2      TrueValue    2016-01-04          12.689
3  ValorRelativo    2016-01-04          12.303

    adj_close_end
          Ticker Fech_Fin_Anal  Cotiz_Fech_Fin
0         Acatis    2018-12-27         240.790
1       Avantage    2018-12-27          12.723
2      TrueValue    2018-12-27          13.965
3  ValorRelativo    2018-12-27          13.421
```

En la columna **Ticker** del dataframe **portfolio_df**, estan los siguientes identificadores, alguno de ellos repetido varias veces.

```
portfolio_df["Ticker"].unique()

array(['TrueValue ', 'ValorRelativo ', 'Advantage ', 'Acatis ', 'EPSV ',
       'DedaloPP ', 'NexusPP ', 'iberdrola', 'telefonica', 'renta_4'],
      dtype=object)
```

Necesito mezclar los tres dataframes, utilizando como clave la columna **Ticker**
Ejecuto

```
merged_portfolio = pd.merge( portfolio_df, adj_close_end,on="Ticker",how = "left")
```

y obtengo

```
  Acquisition Date      Ticker  Quantity      ...        Cost Basis  \
0       2017-10-11  TrueValue    307.296      ...          5528.693   
1       2018-01-08  TrueValue    219.243      ...          3909.314   

   Fech_Fin_Anal Cotiz_Fech_Fin  
0            NaT            NaN  
1            NaT            NaN
```

Intento hacerlo con esta opción.

```
dfs = [portfolio_df, adj_close_start, adj_close_end]
dfs = iter(dfs)
df_final = next(dfs)
for df_ in dfs:
    df_final = df_final.merge(df_, on='Ticker')

print(df_final)
```

y con esta otra

```
from functools import reduce

dfs = [portfolio_df, adj_close_start, adj_close_end]
df_final = reduce(lambda left,right: pd.merge(left,right,on='Ticker'), dfs)
print(df_final)
```

Con ambas obtengo el resultado

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Ticker, Acquisition Date, Quantity, Unit Cost, Cost Basis, Fech_Ini_Anal, Cotiz_Fech_Ini, Fech_Fin_Anal, Cotiz_Fech_Fin]
Index: []
```

En el primer caso no ha incorporado los valores que hay en el dataframe **adj_close_end**. En el segundo y tercero, me devuelve un dataframe vacio.
¿Cual puede ser la causa?. ¿Hay alguna otra manera de conseguir el resultado deseado?. Agradeceré vuestra ayuda.

Finalmente el problema era que la columna "Ticker" de la excel de la que se importa la información en el dataframe portfolio_df, contenía espacios al final de las palabras en algunas de sus celdas, por lo que no coincidian con los valores especificados en la columna Ticker del dataframe que queremos mezclar adj_close_end.
CONCLUSIÓN:
Tener que enfrentar un problema tiene como positivo que el tiempo empleado en el análisis y búsqueda de soluciones, permite profundizar en el conocimiento de métodos y funciones y por ello, no es tiempo perdido.
Por otro lado debemos reflexionar sobre la necesidad de inciar los procesos de análisis eliminando en primer lugar las posibles causas del fallo más sencillas, como así ha sido en este caso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema era que la columna "Ticker" de la excel de la que se importa la información en el dataframe **portfolio_df**, contenía espacios al final de las palabras en algunas de sus celdas, por lo que no coincidian  con los valores especificados en la columna **Ticker** del dataframe que queremos mezclar **adj_close_end**.